# Understanding CDN - do we actually connect to the origin server too?

Tags: server, cdn, cloudflare

TECHNICAL QUESTION --> When connecting to a CDN (eg. cloudflare), does a CDN actually connect to the original shared server when the visitor visits the website? Because if it doesn't connect then probably we don't need to focus ***that much*** on the origin server's speed? Or a CDN does rely on the origin's server's speed?

OPTIONS:

1)use CDN + use cheap shared server (eg. Hostgator)

2)upgrade to VPS or even dedicated server, but do NOT use CDN.

3) use CDN + upgrade to VPS / dedicated server

Which option is recommended when you are on budget? My understanding is that there is no need to upgrade the shared server to VPS, the **CDN is enough as an upgrade**. Or a CDN does rely on the origin's server's speed?

Thanks for any technical insights!

Answer (score 1):

CDN's connect to the origin server to grab static resources the first time. That's images, scripts, stylesheets, fonts, video, etc. They are then stored on the edge servers and future requests don't go to your server.

However html files are NOT cached on the CDN. Every page load hits your origin server through the CDN. You can set up CDN page rules to cache html pages, too, but that's of no use on dynamic sites.

If you have dynamic pages, option (2) is best if on a budget. Especially if you're using WordPress (slow). Money of no concern, (3) is best.